# Spring Data Rest Respository not found

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

I'm trying to implement simple web service using Spring 4. But my userService doesn't seem to work.

I have configuration like this:

```
public class DispatcherServletInitializer extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ PersistenceConfig.class };
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ 
        };
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/api/*"};
    }
}
```

With Persistence config for my in-memory HSQLDB like this:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("example.userService")
@PropertySource("classpath:hibernate.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("example.userService.repo")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    @Autowired
    Environment env;

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        /* ... */
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
                .setType(EmbeddedDatabaseType.HSQL)
                .addScript("classpath:db/data.sql")
                .build();
    }
}
```

I have an entity `User`. And here is my repository:

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource
public interface UserRepo extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
    List<User> findAll();
    List<User> findByFirstName(@Param("firstName") String firstName);
}
```

And I also have na embedded jetty on port 9999 to run this service.

And when jetty starts and i go to `localhost:9999/api/users/` or `/user/1` or smth like that, an error 404 occurs. `findByFirstName` method also does not work.

I think this happens because Servlet Dispatcher doesn't know about my exposed repository. But I also don't know how to 'register' it since I don't want to use *controller* for it.

I have read spring docs [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-commons/docs/1.6.1.RELEASE/reference/html/repositories.html), [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/) and another tutorials but most of them do not provide any configs and describe repositories that *simply just work*.

Any suggestions on what can I do with it and what can cause this problem since nothing is shown in console and in compile-time everything work fine?

Thanks in advance!

**UPD 1:**
I've added `@RepositoryRestResource` to `UesrRepo` according to [Accessing JPA Data with REST](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/) but `/api/users` is still 404.

**UPD 2:**
I've simplified question by removing service-part of it since it requires controller according to @Antoniossss's comment. Not it's just that simple: Which configuration (if any) should I use to expose repository?

Comment: I don't see the controller(s) implementing the /users or /users/1 endpoints

Comment: @chomnoue Doesn't repositories get exposed by their names? I mean UserRepository should be exposed at `/users` or `/user/` (but it's not the best practice to straightly expose them). I'd like to use them however without controllers and services. Is it impossible?

Comment: You need @RepositoryRestResource if you want to expose repositories as rest resources. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Comment: @chomnoue `@RepositoryRestResource is not required for a repository to be exported` according to guide you've submitted. Nevertheless I've added it (also edited question) but it's still 404. By the way in a guide like this I don't see any configuration changes in a servlet dispatcher or any config files. Are there any changes or the bundle that should work is just `Entity - Repo - PersistenceConfig`?

Comment: Have you tried to add `@Repository` annotation as well?

Comment: And why you are duplicating methods from repository into service? Repository will be available via REST directly. Moreover definig service does not mean that it will be available via REST. You need `@RestController` for that. I would remove your `DispatcherServletInitializer` as its is not required for everything to work (including mapping)

Comment: @Antoniossss I've removed service. Now there is just an `entity`, `repo`, `persistence config` and `dispatcherServletInitializer`. It (initializer) remains there since removing it didn't work. And if it won't be here, how Spring should configure database? In my opinion there is still a mess with annotations but I don't know how to solve it

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you missed [Spring data rest configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.configuration) and have only MVC configuration. You need to add bean RepositoryRestConfigurer to your configuration or extend RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter.